# How to Get Text From this Json (Using Json.net JObject)

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have this json

```
{
  "Message": "The request is invalid.",
  "ModelState": {
    "UserExists": [
      "userName already exists in db."
    ]
  }
}
```

I can trying to loop through all the model state errors(in this case only 1 but there could be more)

but I can't figure out how to get the text out.

```
 JObject o = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
                        var errors = o["ModelState"];
                        foreach (var error in errors)
                        {

                        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ModelState` you are getting is an object with a property called `UserExists` which then has an array of error strings.

So you first have to iterate all the properties of the `ModelState` and then all the values within the array.

```
var response = "{\"Message\": \"The request is invalid.\", \"ModelState\": { \"UserExists\": [ \"userName already exists in db.\" ], \"SomeOtherError\": [ \"another error.\", \"two in 1\" ] } }";
var o = JObject.Parse(response);
var errors = o["ModelState"];
foreach (var errorProperty in errors.OfType<JProperty>())
{
    foreach (var error in errorProperty.Values())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", errorProperty.Name, error);
    }
}
```